# Картинка на разных устройствах сползает вправо. Как закрепить ее? objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, изображения, ios7

Картинка на разных устройствах сползает вправо. Как закрепить ее?

```
-(void)questions{
    answerText.text = nil;
    UIImageView *image;
    if(_index == 0){
        if (usersHighestLevel == 0) {
            // QUESTION 1
            question.text = @"1";
            image =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(18,72,284,59)];
            image.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1_1.png"];
            [self.view addSubview:image];
        }
        if (usersHighestLevel == 1) {
            // QUESTION 2
            question.text = @"1";
            image =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(18,72,284,59)];
            image.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1_2.png"];
            [self.view addSubview:image];
        }
```

Comment: Вроде с кодом проблем нет. какой становится фрейм у картинки после сползания? на каких конкретно устройствах работает нормально и где сползает? где картинка находится в иерархии вью?

Comment: на 4 iphone нормально. 5 и 6 сползает вправо. Вроде нормально работает с self.view.frame.size.width/1.1
Может еще есть варианты? Нужно закрепить относительно экранов на разных устройствах.

Comment: так какой все таки фрейм после сползания? и может есть смысл проверить `@2x` и `@3x` изображения, может они сами по себе такие?

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - imageWidht - rightInset` это позволит закрепить картинку на какую то дельту от правого угла. При этом, хорошо было бы задать размеры этой картинки тоже в зависимости от ширины экрана. Использование чисел, которые не являются константами - плохой тон программирования.

Answer (score 0):

Выставите `image.clipsToBounds=YES;` что бы исключить отрисовку за пределами фрейма. (Скорее всего это решит вашу проблему)

Если не решило, то проблема в autoresizingMask или constraints. Попробуйте использовать следующий код

```
image.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin
```

Comment: если картинка с AspectFit то она не может вылазить за фрейм. Присвоение  clipsToBounds (boolean) к UIViewAutoresizingMask (UInt) вообще смысла не несет (предполагаю, что опечатка).

Comment: Да, согласен, по обоим пунктам. В первом я почему-то думал про UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill, а во втором действительно опечатка, исправил

Comment: Добавил self.view.frame.size.width/1.1 На месте.

Comment: autoresizingMask не помогла?

Comment: Нет. Не помогла.

Answer (score 0):

Добавил `self.view.frame.size.width/1.1`
На месте картинки.

Comment: я бы все таки предложил попытаться разобраться в проблеме, чтобы в будущем другие пользователи могли использовать эту информацию.  Делить ширину экрана на 1.1 не выглядит хорошим решением.